# How would I do a forgot password page using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, passwords

Not really sure how to go about this. On it, I'd have the user, password and email input. Would that enough? After checking to make sure the password and email match with the username, what would I do afterwards on the PHP page?

Comment: Isn't it a bit silly asking the user for a password to recover their lost password?

Comment: If the user has their password, why would they be on the "Forgot Password" page?

Comment: How do you know what their password is? You are not storing passwords in clear text are you?

Comment: you havn't accepted answers to any of your questions till now - please change that. from the FAQ: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the

Comment: @oezi: He isn't forced to accept any answers.

Comment: @Josh K: no, he isn't, and i didn't want to say that - but asking 7 question whith none of them having a fitting answer sounds very unlikely. (i havn't read all of that questions, but either some of them _are_ answered but not accepted or Dan is asking extremely complicated (or badly phrased) questions)

Comment: @oezi: Sure, however my opinions on accepted answers are there should be none.

Comment: @Dan: the answers you're getting are a lot better than your question deserves. I hope you'll ask better questions in the future.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple method:

All you'd need is their email address. Get them to type that in and then send a special url with a unique code to their email. At this stage, *do not reset their password*, otherwise any prankster could break anyone else's passwords just by knowing their email address.

Once the user has then opened their email and followed the link, you can let them change it to whatever they want.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways to do a forgotten password:

#### Secret Question

When a user signs up force them to adopt a secret question and answer which you store in the DB (hashed). If the user forgets the password you can ask for the question and Answer. If it matches then allow them to set a new password.

The downside of this is the user can enter simple answers that most people know.

#### Email Link

Send them an email with a link to reset their password typically something like:

```
http://domain.com/passwordreset.php?id=EMAIL_HASH
```

The link should expire at some point (24 hrs is standard).

#### Generate A Password

Randomly generate a new password and email it to them. When they login they must change this temporary password. Benefit is you don't have to worry about weak questions or another column for the email link. But you still have the risk of a plain text password sent via email.

Comment: +1, good answer: clear and concise.

Comment: The email link is the only decent option. Secret questions are annoying and insecure, and resetting passwords without first confirming the user owns the email account is a terrible idea.

Comment: @meagar: Correct, but it's also not halfway secure as it relies on the security of the email address.

Comment: You kind of have it. It's pretty much the absolutely source of identity confirmation.

Comment: Secret questions are insecure if they're asked and answered literally ... they can be effective if the users treat them as separate passwords. Of course it's not nearly as easy to require users to provide effective answers to security questions, but then requiring users to design complex passwords doesn't ensure that they'll protect the passwords either.

Answer (score 0):

In principle this should happen:

1. User enters a valid user name and this is checked against your list of users
2. If found, an email is sent to the user, this email contains a unique link which cannot be guessed
3. The user visits this link to confirm they have access to the email account associated with their account
4. Another email is sent with a newly generated password in, NOT their current password. The users password is set to this newly generated password
5. The user now logs in with their new password and is forced to enter a new password - one they can remember

Answer (score 0):

You need to back up a tiny bit.

How you solve this problem will depend upon what your security and login protocol will be for your application.

Having said that here is what I would do. Upon failed login because of lost password, provide a link to recover password. This link will send email to the email address specified. When the user receives this email, they can click a link that will require them to change their password and log them in. The premise here is that they own the email address and no one else will get this email. This is not the strictest protocol but may be enough for your needs.

In the link in email you will need at least the userid and some sort of key to authenticate the user trying to reset the password. This is so that the web service can't be faked out by typing in a URL. Also, you should never allow this password recovery via email if the user didn't click the link that leads to the email being sent.

Again, this is just a hand wavy first guess because you didn't specify what you need.